# How to compute GPS data?

Tags: c++, c++11, gps

I need to compute GPS data with the following information provided.

```
Bits       size description 
Bits 0-25   26  Latitude    Location latitude   Latitude as 26-bit integer * 100,000
Bits 26-51  26  Longitude   Location longitude  Longitude as 26-bit integer * 100,000
```

Based on the above information, I understand that 
1) latitude value could be +-90.xxxxxx i.e. it needs 7 bits to accommodate value of 90 (2 ^ 7). based on the information how do I compute the Latitude and convert into mantissa (7 bits) and exponent (19 bits) part. Also, how about the sign bit ? for example the value 87.45 needs to be stored in a way that 87 gets stored to 7 bits where as 19 bits stores the value 45.

2) Similar Longitude value could be +-180 which requires 8 bits to accommodate value of 180 (2 ^8)based on the information how do I compute the Longitude and convert into mantissa (8 bits) and exponent(18 bits) part. Also, how about the sign bit ?

for example the value 130.50 needs to be stored in a way that 130 gets stored to 8 bits where as 18 bits stores the value 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking at this wrong… you're being given a 52-bit value containing lat and lon as integer values, right? Don't worry about the mantissa. You need to look at the two parts of the input as separate integers, and divide each by 100,000 to get degrees.

Try something like:

```
#include <stdint.h>
int main() {
  int64_t input = yourGpsVal();
  // note: lat/lon may be the wrong way round
  // strip off the rightmost 26 bits and convert to double
  double lat = ( input >> 26 ) / 100000.;
  // zero the bits left of the rightmost 26 and convert to double
  double lon = ( input % ( 1 << 26 )) / 100000.;
}
```

Have a look at this demo on Wandbox. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xtiDOfMKH0wK5LIC